# unable to use getElementById on HTML element not yet appended to document

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have the following bit of js which creates a div, doesn't yet append it to the page but does populate it with some HTML. I can query that HTML with `getElementsByClassName` as shown in the alert which correctly alerts as "2".

However trying to use getElementById on the same element results in an error "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'"

```
function verbatim(fn) {
    return fn.toString().split("/*")[1].split("*/")[0];
}

var aggregatorContainer = document.createElement("div");
aggregatorContainer.id = "usageByCampusNow";

var someHTML = verbatim(function () {/*
            <h2>Lab Locations and Current Use</h2>

            <div class='campusIndicator master'>
                <div id='masterAggregator'>

                    <div id='masterSelector'>
                        <div class='aggDetails'>
                            <h3 id="masterSelection"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='masterOptions'><ul id='masterOptionsList'></ul></div>

                    <div class='guageContainer'>
                        <div class='campusGuage'>
                            <span><img class='clockhand' src='/images/labs/handred2.png'></span>
                            <span><img class='clockhand' src='/images/labs/hand2.png'></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class='txtUse'></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        */
});

aggregatorContainer.innerHTML = someHTML;
alert(aggregatorContainer.getElementsByClassName("clockhand").length);
try {
    var masterAggContainer = aggregatorContainer.getElementById("masterAggregator"); // issue
}
catch (err) {
    alert(err); // Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementById'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zougwm9/

The simple solution is that I add the element to the page

```
 document.getElementById("someElement").appendChild(aggregatorContainer);
```

and then I can use document.getElementById to get elements within `aggregatorContainer` to my hearts delight but I was hoping that I could do all the prep on the HTML before appending it to the page in case something went wrong and I ended up with a funky element stinking up the page. So I'd like to query `aggregatorContainer.getElementById` before adding it to the page

Essentially, why can't I use `getElementById` on this element before it's appended? `getElementsByClassName` seems to be fine!

Comment: by the way, you still can use `jQuery(aggregatorContainer).find('[id="masterAggregator"]')[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN documentation for `Document.getElementsByClassName`:

> - getElementsByClassName can be called on any element, not only on the document. The element on which it is called will be used as the root of the search.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

`Document.getElementById` does not have that note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

The difference is that `getElementsByClassName` seems to be inherited by `NodeList`s from `Document` whereas `getElementById` is not. The reason I assume is that `getElementsByClassName` returns what it is working on , which is a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`, thus allowing for chainability; whereas `getElementById` will always return zero or one `Node`s or `HTMLElement`s.

Comment: Thanks for that. The getElementById link mentions the alternative `querySelector` which seems to work on the element before it's appended - so: `querySelector("#masterAggregator")`. I'll refactor and confirm. The omission of the note on the second link doesn't quite confirm the case for me though and I don't follow why the single node vs NodeList means it doesn't work on elements not attached to the document.

Comment: Have you tried `getElementById` on existing NodeLists in the DOM? The error message you reported suggests that `NodeList` does not have a property called `getElementById` - which supposedly means it doesn't matter if the NodeList is part of the DOM or not - unless the method is inherited when *added*  the DOM.

Comment: Correct, `getElementById` can only be called directly from document. As the link you provide states "there is no need for 'local' versions of the function". It also states "Elements not in the document are not searched by getElementById()". But you'd think `document.createElement` would make it part of the document, attached or not. But it goes on: "When creating an element and assigning it an ID, you have to insert the element into the document tree... before you can access it with getElementById." That explains it but sort of doesn't, kind of "just because". I guess I'll just add it hidden!