# how to pass event in innerhtml by onclick

Tags: javascript, events

I am making a project about add to cart. I want to pass event by onclick from innerhtml.
Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Add to cart</title>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="cards-container" class="row align-items-center my-3 p-3"></div>
 <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my js code

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>show(data))

function show(data){
 const cardsContainer = document.getElementById('cards-container');
 cardsContainer.innerHTML='';
 data.map(element => {
    const cardDiv = document.createElement('div')
    cardDiv.className= "col-md-4"
    cardDiv.innerHTML=`
    <div class='card p-5 m-1'>
        <h3>${element.name}</h3>
        <h5>${element.email}</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id='card-button' onclick='setLocalStorage(e)'>Add to Card</button>
    </div>
    `
    cardsContainer.appendChild(cardDiv);
});
}

function setLocalStorage(e){
 console.log("clicked",e)
}
```

I got this error in console https://d.pr/i/JCjI77

Comment: The most "correct" approach I can think of is to create your `button` element separately, apply your `onclick` handler, then add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this issue a few times before as well.

First, I would suggest using jquery anyway. When writing plain html, I almost always use jquery. It makes interaction with the DOM much easier. So here is an example in jquery of the onClick event for an element with id="card-button". A normal click event won't work from jquery here. You have to set it on the document and then further set a selector:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>show(data))

function show(data){
 const cardsContainer = $('#cards-container');
 cardsContainer.html("");
 data.map(element => {
    cardsContainer.append(`
    <div class='card p-5 m-1 col-md-4'>
        <h3>${element.name}</h3>
        <h5>${element.email}</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id='card-button'>Add to Card</button>
    </div>
    `
});
}

$(document).on("click", "#card-button", function(e) {
    setLocalStorage(e)

    // or you can just place the contents of setLocalStorage directly 
    // into here! 
})

function setLocalStorage(e){
 console.log("clicked",e)
}
```

you can remove onClick from the button element here. Make sure you remember to import jquery. Ideally the minified version.

**BUT YOU HAVE ANOTHER MORE IMPORTANT ISSUE**

you're creating multiple add card buttons with the same id (card-button). you need to set card-button as a class. This way it can be applied multiple elements. I would suggest adding an ID to the button or cardDiv that is associated with userID, Index or any other unique identifier. This way you can recognize which user or card button is actually being pressed, and take action accordingly. Here is the updated jQuery with class instead of ID

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>show(data))

function show(data){
 const cardsContainer = $('#cards-container');
 cardsContainer.html("");
 data.map(element => {
    cardsContainer.append(`
    <div class='card p-5 m-1 col-md-4'>
        <h3>${element.name}</h3>
        <h5>${element.email}</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" class="card-button" id='some-unique-id'>Add to Card</button>
    </div>
    `
});
}

$(document).on("click", ".card-button", function(e) {
    setLocalStorage(e)

    // or you can just place the contents of setLocalStorage directly into here! 

    // Here you can grab the jquery object with $(this), or use the 
    // ID with e.target.id with the e.target.id, etc...
    clickedButton = $(this);
    clickedButtonID = e.target.id;
})

function setLocalStorage(e){
 console.log("clicked",e)
}
```

I don't use plain HTML without jQuery often, so I can't answer for sure if you want to take that route. It seems as if this previous thread answers that question, definitely better than I could.

[unable to use getElementById on HTML element not yet appended to document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186062/unable-to-use-getelementbyid-on-html-element-not-yet-appended-to-document)

Best of luck!!

Comment: Using `getElementById` and `createElement` when you're adamant about using jQuery doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Agreed, I just didn't change the code that was working. But if he chooses to switch to jQuery, I definitely change it to be more consistent.

Comment: Also, I'm all for plain JS, I just don't use it often. I've ran into this issue before while using jQuery and it took me a bit to find a solution. I'm sure there are more solutions without jQuery.

Comment: But your whole answer is that the OP must switch to jQuery, so you could at least be consistent with the code in your answer.

Comment: I suggest he switches to jQuery, point out he definitely needs to change the ID issue to classes, and then provide a thread that solves the issue in plain JS.

Comment: But I agree, I should have spent the time to change the other functions into jQuery. I was just a bit lazy with my answer

Comment: Sorry. I'm not trying to be a pain but it's important (to me at least) that answers are not confusing.

Comment: Agreed. I'll go ahead and edit it. Bad answers on here are a pain in the ass so thanks for calling me on it.

Comment: Ha. And sometimes I need to stop being a Senior Engineer and stop bossing people about. Hope the coding is going well.

Comment: Lol. Everyone needs to be checked and to check. If you have the chance to review and see if it is more consistent now, awesome.

Comment: I use your jquery concept but got this error https://d.pr/i/WSHwhZ @BradyAgranoff

Comment: Did you import jquery? Add this to your html, above the other script tags: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: For this example to work you need to include jQuery. Probably the minified version [you can find here](https://releases.jquery.com/). But make sure you include it before your `script.js`. @MahmudulRana

Comment: you can even add it to the <head> if you want, but typically it is better practice to put all the scripts just above the closing </body> tag